# How to set language for Google PlaceAutocomplete

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using Google PlaceAutocomplete, so the user can select his address.

My code is:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()

                .setCountry("IQ")
                .build();


        mAutocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, typeFilter);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();

            mNameView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAddress() + ""));


        }
    };
```

I want the result in Arabic. After some research I found that it depends on user system language, is there a way to make it only in Arabic?

Comment: Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303599/4516797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. You can use **web api**, but:

> The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, if possible.

More: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

You can change it in the `initialize` call:

```
Places.initialize(applicationContext, "API_KEY", Locale.US)
```

The third parameter is the language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of the languages supported https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport & you may get language code from here.

So when you are calling place detail api, you may add `language` parameter which is optional, to see the details at following url 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Answer (score 0):

**Places API** returns you the Place object with the short address and latlng coordinates, but to get the full address with the **EN locale** you can do with this:

```
public Address getFullAddress(Place place){
        Address address;

        Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").build();
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, aLocale);

        try
        {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude, 1);

            address = addresses.get(0);

            return address;

        } catch (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```